# How to create a Postgres table with unique combined primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, ddl, unique-constraint

I have two tables named `players` & `matches` in a Postgres DB as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    name text NOT NULL,
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE matches (
    winner int REFERENCES players (id),
    loser int REFERENCES players (id),
    -- to prevent rematch btw players
    CONSTRAINT unique_matches
    PRIMARY KEY (winner, loser)
);
```

How can I ensure that only a unique combination of either `(winner, loser)` or `(loser, winner)` is used for `matches` primary key so that the `matches` table won't allow the insertion of:

```
INSERT INTO matches VALUES (2, 1);
```

If it already has a row containing `VALUES (1, 2)` like :

```
 winner | loser
--------+-------
      1 |     2
```

The goal is to avoid entry of matches between the same players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX matches_uni_idx ON matches
   (greatest(winner, loser), least(winner, loser));
```

Can't be a [`UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), since those only work with columns, not expressions.

You might add a `serial` column to serve as PK, but with just two integer columns, your original PK is very efficient, too (see comments). And it makes both columns `NOT NULL` automatically. (Else, add `NOT NULL` constraints.)

You also might add a `CHECK` constraint to rule out players playing against themselves:

```
CHECK (winner <> loser)
```

Hint: To search for a pair of IDs (where you don't know who won), build the same expressions into your query, and the index will be used:

```
SELECT * FROM matches
WHERE  greatest(winner, loser) = 3  -- the greater value, obviously
AND    least(winner, loser) = 1;
```

If you deal with unknown parameters and you don't know which is greater ahead of time:

```
WITH input AS (SELECT $id1 AS _id1, $id2 AS _id2)  -- input once
SELECT * FROM matches, input
WHERE  greatest(winner, loser) = greatest(_id1, _id2)
AND    least(winner, loser) = least(_id1, _id2);
```

The CTE wrapper is just for convenience to enter parameters once only and not necessary in some contexts.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin. it worked like a charm ;) however, is there a reason that you suggested to use a `serial` column to serve as PK as opposed to  the way I previously had (`PRIMARY KEY (winner, loser)`)?Thanks again :)

Comment: @BabakK: You are right, `PRIMARY KEY (winner, loser)` would work this way. And with two integer columns, it's very efficient, too. If you have FK references to the table it might be simpler to use a single-column surrogate PK.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't support constraints on expressions, so I can't think of a direct way of expressing this requirement as a constraint. One thing you could do, though, is change the table's structure so it has two columns for the players of the match (the primary key), a constraint that ensures that player1 always has the smaller id of the two and an additional column to indicate the winner:

```
CREATE TABLE matches (
    p1 int REFERENCES players (id),
    p2 int REFERENCES players (id),
    p1winner boolean,

    CONSTRAINT matches_pk PRIMARY KEY (p1, p2),
    CONSTRAINT matches_players_order CHECK (p1 < p2)
);
```