# Generate matrix of access in source-target table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I have two tables in PostgreSQL, `class` and `inheritance`.
Each row in `inheritance` has 2 class IDs `source_id` and `target_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.class (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('class_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT class_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.inheritance (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('inherited_id_seq'::regclass),
    source_id bigint NOT NULL,
    target_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT inherited_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT inherited_source_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (source_id)
        REFERENCES public.class (id),
    CONSTRAINT inherited_target_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (target_id)
        REFERENCES public.class (id)
)
```

I want to create Access Matrix between all classes based in inheritance relationship in inheritance table.
I try this code:

```
select * , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=1) then 1 else 0 end as "1"   
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=2) then 1 else 0 end as "2"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=3) then 1 else 0 end as "3"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=4) then 1 else 0 end as "4"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=5) then 1 else 0 end as "5"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=6) then 1 else 0 end as "6"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=7) then 1 else 0 end as "7"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=8) then 1 else 0 end as "8"
         , case when id in (select target_id from inheritance where source_id=9) then 1 else 0 end as "9"
from class
```

and get the right answer, but it's just for 9 static rows in class.

[image]

How can I get all number of rows in class using a dynamic SQL command?

If we can't do it with SQL, **how can we do it with PL/pgSQL?**

Comment: AFAIK you simply cannot achieve this. You need to know the number of columns beforehand. You cannot create a query with an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: What do you mean with "*If we can't do it with SQL*"? Do you have flexibility on the DMBS to be used?

Comment: I need dynamic SQL command in PostgreSQL to do that, if it is impossible, I need PL/pgSQL commands, just in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please post sample input data as formatted text - **no images** - and the expected results of that data. See [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for good method to create formatted text. Even better provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Static solution

SQL demands to know name and type of each result column (and consequently their number) at call time. You cannot derive result columns from data dynamically with plain SQL. You can use an array or a document type instead of separate columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   class c
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT target_id AS id, array_agg(source_id) AS sources
   FROM  (SELECT source_id, target_id FROM inheritance i ORDER BY 1,2) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) i USING (id);
```

| id | name | sources |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 | {2,3,4} |
| 2 | c2 | {5} |
| 3 | c3 | {5,6,7} |
| 4 | c4 | {7} |
| 5 | c5 | {8} |
| 6 | c6 | {9} |
| 7 | c7 | {9} |
| 8 | c8 | *null* |
| 9 | c9 | *null* |

#### Dynamic solution

If that's not good enough you need dynamic SQL with two round-trips to the DB server: 1. Generate SQL. 2. Execute SQL. Using the `crosstab()` function from the additional module `tablefunc`. If you are unfamiliar, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

1. Generate SQL:

```sql
SELECT format(
$q$SELECT *
FROM   class c
LEFT   JOIN crosstab(
   'SELECT target_id, source_id, 1 FROM inheritance ORDER BY 1,2'
 , 'VALUES (%s)'
   ) AS ct (id int, %s int)
     USING (id)
ORDER  BY id;
$q$
        , string_agg(c.id::text, '), (')
        , string_agg('"' || c.id || '"', ' int, ')
      )
FROM  (SELECT id FROM class ORDER BY 1) c;
```

Returns a query of this form, which we ...
2. Execute:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   class c
LEFT   JOIN crosstab(
   'SELECT target_id, source_id, 1 FROM inheritance ORDER BY 1,2'
 , 'VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)'
   ) AS ct (id int, "1" int, "2" int, "3" int, "4" int, "5" int, "6" int, "7" int, "8" int, "9" int)
     USING (id)
ORDER  BY id;
```

... to get:

```
 id | name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
----+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
  1 | c1   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |  
  2 | c2   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   |   |   |  
  3 | c3   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |  
  4 | c4   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   |  
  5 | c5   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |  
  6 | c6   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1
  7 | c7   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1
  8 | c8   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  
  9 | c9   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f7642969c1b5c720094d56614237891)*

See:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)
- [Dynamically convert hstore keys into columns for an unknown set of keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123006/3684)

#### Dynamic execution with psql

Still two round-trips to the server, but only a single command.
Both of the following solutions use psql meta-commands and only work from within psql!

#### With `\gexec`

Using the standard interactive terminal, you can feed the generated SQL back to the Postgres server for execution directly with `\gexec`:

```sql
test=> SELECT format(
$q$SELECT *
FROM   class c
LEFT   JOIN crosstab(
'SELECT target_id, source_id, 1 FROM inheritance ORDER BY 1,2'
, 'VALUES (%s)'
) AS ct (id int, %s int)
  USING (id)
ORDER  BY id;
$q$
     , string_agg(c.id::text, '), (')
     , string_agg('c' || c.id, ' int, ')
   )
FROM  (SELECT id FROM class ORDER BY 1) c\gexec
```

Same result.

##### With `\crosstabview`

```sql
test=> SELECT *
test-> FROM   class c
test-> LEFT   JOIN (
test(>    SELECT target_id AS id, source_id, 1 AS val
test(>    FROM   inheritance
test(>    ) i USING (id)
test-> \crosstabview id source_id val
 id | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |  
----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--
  1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |   | 
  2 |   |   |   | 1 |   |   |   |   | 
  3 |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   | 
  4 |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   |   | 
  5 |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   | 
  6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 
  7 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1 | 
  8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
  9 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
(9 rows)
```

See (with related answers for both):

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159280/3684)

There are lots of subtleties in these solutions ...

#### Aside

Assuming there are some mechanisms in place to disallow duplicates and directly contradicting relationships. Like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX inheritance_uni_idx
ON inheritance (GREATEST(source_id, target_id), LEAST(source_id, target_id));
```

See:

- [How to create a Postgres table with unique combined primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705305/how-to-create-a-postgres-table-with-unique-combined-primary-key/33705450#33705450)