# Looking by two columns, interchangable values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table example:

| id | lang_from | lang_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chi | eng |

So the table contains information about translations, the translation has a direction (from and to), but when I do search the direction is not important:

```
WHERE (lang_from = 'chi' AND lang_to='eng') OR (lang_from = 'eng' AND lang_to='chi')
```

Is this an efficient way for the lookup?

P.S. I don't have indexes set, as long as it would give me an extremely low selectivity.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain with examples, sample datas and expected result ?

Comment: You could try greatest() and least() like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pGChO03l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the search efficient, consider an expression index of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (GREATEST(lang_from, lang_to), LEAST(lang_from, lang_to));
```

And a matching predicate in queries:

```
WHERE GREATEST(lang_from, lang_to) = GREATEST('chi', 'eng')
AND   LEAST(lang_from, lang_to)    = LEAST('chi', 'eng')
```

Or simply:

```
WHERE GREATEST(lang_from, lang_to) = 'eng'
AND   LEAST(lang_from, lang_to)    = 'chi'
```

Depending on the complete scenario, variations of this index may be useful. Like adding another (selective) index field.

This only makes sense in combination with a matching index - and selective enough predicates, so that the index is actually used. Else your original form is even slightly faster.

Related:

- [How to create a Postgres table with unique combined primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705305/how-to-create-a-postgres-table-with-unique-combined-primary-key/33705450#33705450)