# Select unique rows based on combination of 2 equivalent columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below:

| city1 | city2 | dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | Berlin | 7900 |
| Berlin | New York | 7900 |
| Oregon | Ohio | 5700 |
| Montreal | Rio | 5700 |
| Ohio | Oregon | 5700 |
| Rio | Montreal | 5700 |
| Moscow | Tokyo | 4200 |
| Tokyo | Moscow | 4200 |

Both row 1 and row 2 are same things and the only difference is in the first one Berlin is city2 and in the second one Berlin is city1.
I want to show this kind of rows only once...

How to do it?

Comment: If you want to enforce that such rows can only appear once then add constraints `UNIQUE (city1, city2)` and `CHECK (city1 < city2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self LEFT JOIN  and see if any matches are there

Depending on th last OR condition you can choose which cite are shown in the result set

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.city1 = t2.city2 and t2.city2 = t1.city1 AND t1.dist = t2.dist
WHERE t2.city1 IS NULL 
  OR t1.city1 > t1.city2
```

| city1 | city2 | dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Conce | Santiago | 500 |
| New York | Berlin | 7900 |
| Oregon | Ohio | 5700 |
| Rio | Montreal | 5700 |
| Talca | Linares | 80 |
| Tokyo | Moscow | 4200 |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.city1 = t2.city2 and t2.city2 = t1.city1 AND t1.dist = t2.dist
WHERE t2.city1 IS NULL 
  OR t2.city1 > t2.city2
```

| city1 | city2 | dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | New York | 7900 |
| Conce | Santiago | 500 |
| Montreal | Rio | 5700 |
| Moscow | Tokyo | 4200 |
| Ohio | Oregon | 5700 |
| Talca | Linares | 80 |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CkpkFzZx)

Answer (score 2):

Works with a single table scan, substantially faster than joining to another instance:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
       LEAST   (city1, city2) AS city1
     , GREATEST(city1, city2) AS city2
     , dist
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 1, 2, dist;  -- optional sort & tiebreaker
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MAKD04X4)

The city that sorts alphabetically first is reported as `city1`.
Works for any number of duplicates.
The added `ORDER BY` picks the row with the smallest `dist`, while also ordering rows. Optional if you don't need either. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

You might want a multicolumn `UNIQUE` index on the expressions to disallow any such (switched) duplicates to begin with. See:

- [How to create a Postgres table with unique combined primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705305/how-to-create-a-postgres-table-with-unique-combined-primary-key/33705450#33705450)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```sql
select a.*
from t a
left join t b on b.city1 = a.city2 and b.city2 = a.city1
where b.city1 is null or b.city1 > b.city2
```

I added a couple of unmatched edge cases in the [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rw8KP6Rw).

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement to ensure that the smaller of the two city names always appears first.I mean, "a" is minimal and Z is maximal.s minimal and Z is maximal. This way, each pair will have a unique representation.
Then，group the data by the newly ordered city pairs and then filter out duplicates.

Comment: Maybe add an example in SQL of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

JOINs are unnecessary! Here's a simple query that works beautifully:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE city1 < city2
```

This filters out all duplicate rows, leaving only the canonical rows where the city names appear in alphabetical order.